# Not receiving money through Paypal Express Checkout API

Tags: paypal

I developed a small payment process that uses the Express Checkout API. I'm testing the code with my friend's account with $1. My payment process is redirecting to the live paypal site, he enters his information and pays, he is redirected to my confirmation thank you page, but I never receive funds. I've checked my API credentials in the code, and they are OK. I'm receiving a token and paypal payerid info on my confirmation screen. What could be the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did the amount get deducted from his account and does the transaction show up in this account history?

Answer (score 3):

See my answer in [Why is DoExpressCheckoutPayment required for Paypal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984864/why-is-doexpresscheckoutpayment-required-for-paypal)
In order to use Express Checkout, you must call at least the following API calls:
1. SetExpressCheckout -- to set up the transaction.
2. DoExpressCheckoutPayment -- to finalize the transaction.

If you don't call DoExpressCheckoutPayment on the 'Thank you' page, the transaction is not completed. This is by design to allow for greater flexibility

Express Checkout is intended as a drop-in solution in your own checkout process. After Express Checkout redirects you back to your site, you're supposed to show an order confirmation where the buyer can review his/her final order details before initiating a button / link which initiates the final DoExpressCheckoutPayment API call. This is why DoExpressCheckoutPayment is required.