# Japanese characters not shown in PayPal IPN Notification

Tags: paypal-ipn

In PayPal (sandbox) I defined a Japanese User with a first name and a last name with Japanese characters.

However, the IPN notification I receive is encoded with charset=windows-1252. Indeed this is one of the parameters in the HTTP request received from Paypal.

I would like to greet the user using his/her name, but since what I seem to receive is not Unicode, I would be sending garbage characters instead of the payers name.

Is there any way to get the IPN notification from Paypal sent to my listener in Unicode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is DoExpressCheckoutPayment required for Paypal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984864/why-is-doexpresscheckoutpayment-required-for-paypal)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/ipn/pdt/ipn-encoding-returns-invalid

You should go to **Profile**->**Selling Preferences**->**Language Encoding**->**More Options**.

Answer (score 0):

New path for this setting:
**Profile ->  My selling tools -> PayPal button language encoding -> More Options -> "Do you want to use the same encoding for data sent from PayPal to you (e.g., IPN, downloadable logs, emails)?" -> select "No, use: UTF8"**