# PayPal IPN Simulator Character Encoding

Tags: character-encoding, paypal-ipn

Is there a way to set the character encoding that PayPal uses for IPNs in the IPN simulator?  For real accounts and IPNs you can change this as described in this answer: [Japanese characters not shown in PayPal IPN Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149457/japanese-characters-not-shown-in-paypal-ipn-notification)

But I cannot find a way to do the same for the simulator.  All I get sent from PayPal as the name is "%3F" or "?" characters instead of Chinese or Japanese characters.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to do this from the IPN simulator.  However, you can use the sandbox to test payments, and set up your merchant account for a specific character encoding.  You would just need to log into your merchant account that you are testing with and go to your profile and make your way to the language encoding preferences.

Log in > Profile > Language Encoding > More Options

Comment: I thought this was the case. Are there problems with PayPal's Sandbox accounts since their site update? I can't seem to login with my sandbox merchant account to be able to do this.

Comment: There are some issues.  Most have been resolved by clearing cookies and cache prior to logging into developer.paypal.com.  Also, there are more issues with IE than Firefox and Chrome, so you may try using one of those browsers.  If you are still having an issue, please describe where specifically your having the issue at and whats happening.  If its an issue with navigating to the page without getting an error, direct links to the page will work for some pages.

Comment: All sorted now thanks. I just had to create all new sandbox accounts. The old ones didn't work. Still seems a bit buggy though. As you said, you need to clear your cookies and cache randomly to make it work.

Comment: We're working on the issues as they are reported.  Some of them may take some time, but we are working on them.  :)

Comment: paypal, why not just use utf-8 for all ipn posts?